# Smart pointer as condition: are if (p) and if (p.get()) equilavent?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Let `p` be a shared/unique pointer. Are `if (p)` and `if (p.get())` equivalent?

If not, in what cases can these conditionals, or the code within the conditionals, behave differently?

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_bool) I read that `std::shared_ptr::operator bool` checks whether `get() != nullptr`. Is this the exact implementation of `operator bool`?

Comment: Do you not believe cppreference?

Comment: @NathanOliver I generally did! Just wanted to make sure about this one because my shared pointers are used in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: Why multithreaded environment makes this any different?

Comment: @Slava Good question - I guess I haven't exactly thought through why that is. I guess I was worried the underlying object getting deleted within the `if`. But either way, `p` will be in scope within the if condition, keeping a reference count (if `p` is valid pointer of course)

Comment: If you have race condition over shared shared_ptr - if(p.get()) would not make it any better, IMHO it would make it worse. There is `std::atomic` specialization for `std::shared_ptr` or you should use mutex.

Comment: Found it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic), thanks for pointing that out! `atomic_store` got rid of a lock I had that swaps two `shared_ptr`s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "exact implementation" should not be your concern (it will vary from compiler to compiler, from version to version, and possibly based on the options you provide to the compiler)

Your concern should be "How will a standards-compliant compiler behave" and the answer is "Yes, `if(ptr)` should always produce the same results as `if(ptr.get())`

From the standard:

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type  bool. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to  false; any other value is converted to  true . A prvalue of type  std::nullptr_t can be converted to a prvalue of type  bool ; the resulting value is  false .

And smart pointers count as  [nullable pointers](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/nullablepointer.requirements#3) which have the following requirement:

> An object p of type P can be contextually converted to bool (Clause [conv]). The effect shall be as if p != nullptr had been evaluated in place of p.

(thanks to T.C. for this quote)

Comment: Technically, that quote isn't enough, since `unique_ptr` supports fancy pointers and its `pointer` isn't necessarily a built-in pointer. However, that's covered by the `NullablePointer` requirements.

Comment: Agreed, but I couldn't find a succinct quote that covered the possibilities for "smart pointers".  As Far As I Know, though, all the standard and boost smart pointers behave the way you expect them to -- the point I was trying to make [spend your effort worrying about other stuff and trust the compiler to get it right [unless you are multithreading (which was added to the comments later) in which case do not expect the compiler to read your mind]]

Comment: [\[unique.ptr.single\]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/unique.ptr.single#3), in conjunction with [\[nullablepointer.requirements\]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/nullablepointer.requirements#3).

Answer (score 1):

The purpose behind `operator bool()` on smart pointers is to make smart pointers behave like regular pointers in a common situation of performing a validity check, i.e. in situations when you write

```
if (myPointer) {
    ... // Do something
}
```

The exact implementation may be different. Instead of calling `get()` and comparing the result to `nullptr` a standard-compliant implementation could, for example, check a member variable that stores the value returned by `get()`, or check a private flag indicating that the pointer is not pointing to anything valid.

For programmers' purposes, however, it is enough to know that the implementation would return `true` any time when `get()` returns a non-null value, and that it would also return `false` when `get()` returns `nullptr`.

Answer (score 1):

> Are `if (p)` and if `(p.get())` equivalent?

From [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_bool) (same applies for `unique_ptr`):

> Checks if `*this` stores a non-null pointer, i.e. whether `get() != nullptr`.

Yes, `if (p)` and `if (p.get())` have equivalent behaviour. No, pedantically speaking they are not exactly equivalent: the former has a function call, the latter has a different function call and a pointer comparison. In practice, both are likely to generate identical code.

> If not, in what cases can these conditionals, or the code within the conditionals, behave differently?

They behave exactly the same.

> Is this the exact implementation of operator bool?

This is exactly how the implementation must behave.

The exact implementation is... implementation defined. You can read the sources of your standard library implementation to find out.

Answer (score 1):

They behave exactly the same.

In order to find out the various ways in which we could use a pointer null check you could see the following

http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html

Which is called the safe bool idiom. Even though it may seem to be obselete in c++11, it gives a good exposer on the usage of bool operations on sharedPtrs.